# jQuery calendar/date picker

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

How do I place a date picker in my website, like http://www.avis.co.uk/?

Comment: What have you tried ? Can you show us your code ? What specific problem do you have ? Do you get an error message of some kind ? Help us help you ;-)

Comment: First you help yourself by reading the documentation of date picker

Comment: seriously 2 months 11 questions and not a single accept ! please accept the some answers to your questions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at [jQuery UI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery_UI), http://jqueryui.com/.

It supports a date picker.

Answer (score 1):

Not the same, but you can try one of following:

1. [jQuery UI -- datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/)
2. [keith-wood.name_datepick](http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html)

I hope this helps.

For more, search on the Internet. You will easily find lots of jQuery plugins available for free out there.